# How to reset a Rectangle's x,y,width,height, after transform

Tags: konvajs

I have an app that uses konvajs, where I set rectangles to be resizable. I have it set such that after I transform the rectangle I set the scaleX and scaleY to 1 so I can just use x, y, width, and height. I do this with the following code:

```
myRectangle.on('transformend',  function() {
    myRectangle.width(Math.round(myRectangle.width() * myRectangle.scaleX()));
    myRectangle.height(Math.round(myRectangle.height() * myRectangle.scaleY()));
    myRectangle.scaleX(1);
    myRectangle.scaleY(1);
});
```

However, sometimes after I resize (usually if I "flip" the rectangle by dragging up or to the left), the x, y, width and height are strange values.  Sometimes the width or height is negative, sometimes it seems like the x and y positions do not refer to the top left of the rectangle.  I want to be able to extract information about the rectangle, so I would like position to be top left of the rectangle with positive width and height values.  I don't mind resetting these values after the rectangle is tranformed, but I am not quite sure how konvajs is calculating the x,y,width, and height so I can't properly reset them.  Is there some metric indicating when a tranform "flips" a rectangle? Or some other way to reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting flipEnabled and rotationEnabled to false on the transformer prevents rotations from happening.

Answer (score 1):

To get a visual sense of what is happening to the attrs during the transform, take a look at the demo in the official docs [here](https://konvajs.org/docs/select_and_transform/Transform_Events.html) and pay special attention to width/height, rotation and scale as you resize by dragging the right edge first, then repeat with the bottom edge.

It will help to understand that dragging a Transformer handle changes the scale of the rectangle - not the width or height. However this is not the end of the story - if you 'flip' the shape in the horizontal axis then you will see that the rotation is changed from zero to 180 degrees and the scaleX remains positive. But if you drag and flip the shape in the vertical axis then there is no rotation effect and the scaleY switches to negative.

Long story short - at the moment I can't think of a useful use-case that requires trying to redraw the rectangle without scale or rotation affects, which I will refer to as the 'plain' rect versus the 'exotic' rect you get after using the Transformer.

If the use-case is hit detection via your own math then you have everything you need to know in the rects x & y, width & height, rotation and scaleX & scaleY. Even if you *could* get the attrs for a plain rect you would still have the same params to plug into your math, so recomputing the plain rect  is wasted effort.

If the use-case is storage (serialization) of the rect's attrs then again the same point as above - you need to store the position, rotation, size, and scale so as to be able to redraw it later.

A legitimate use-case for resetting scale to 1 would be if your app's business case requires it. But this only covers resetting:

```
rect.seAttrs({
    width: rect.width() * scaleX,
    height: rect.height() * scaleY,
    scaleX: 1,
    scaleY: 1
  }
```

and leaves the rect at the same position and rotation.

Conclusion: attempting to recompute a plain rect from an exotic rect may not be worth the effort in some cases.