# KonvaJS: How to know updated width and height of shape after applying transformation using transformer

Tags: konvajs, konva

After applying transformation using transformer on a shape, its scaleX and scaleY properties are changed where as its width and height property remains the same.

But I need to calculate the updated width and height of shape after applying transformation.
Can anybody tell me the work around code/solution to get the width and height of the shape

I have seen other questions and applied it but the problem persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset a Rectangle's x,y,width,height, after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932900/how-to-reset-a-rectangles-x-y-width-height-after-transform)

Comment: I tried it but it did not work.

Comment: @DijkstraAlgorithm make a demo of your issue

Comment: @lavrton , https://jsbin.com/goxuyekehi/edit?js,output.

Comment: @DijkstraAlgorithm the custom shape in this demo doesn't have width and height properties.

Comment: @lavrton, updated demo jsbin.com/ludojaz/2/edit?js,output , it contains width and height in list named boundary